# How to solve master theorem $T(n) = 3T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n^2}{\log_2 n}$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Im trying to solve this using master theorem  $T(n) = 3T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + \frac{n^2}{\log_2 n}$ but I dont know how.

So far we know that $a=3$, $b=2$, $f(n) = \frac{n^2}{\log_2 n}$.

Which rule to apply now and how to solve this?

Comment: Use `\log_2(n)` to get "$\log_2(n)$".

Comment: Another option to solve this, rather than blindly applying Master Theorem, is to *think* about it and to solve the recursion for the modified variable $$S(k)=3^{-k}T(2^k).$$ This reads $$S(k)=S(k-1)+\frac{r^k}k\qquad r=\frac43,$$ thus, $$S(k)=S(0)+\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{r^i}i, $$ which, since $r>1$, yields readily $$S(k)=\Theta\left(\frac{r^k}k\right),$$ hence $$T(2^k)=\Theta\left(3^k\frac{r^k}k\right)=\Theta\left(\frac{4^k}k\right).$$ Finally, $n=2^k$ is equivalent to $k=\log_2n$ hence, assuming for example that $(T(n))$ is nondecreasing, one gets $$T(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 cases to the Master theorem for solving the recurrence $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)=3T(n/2)+n^2 / (\log n)$.  If you draw out the recursion tree, the cost of the root is $f(n)$ and the cost of all the leaves is $n^{\log_b a}$. We compare these two costs and we get the three different cases for the Master theorem.  Since the cost of the root $f(n) = n^2 / \log n$ is polynomially larger than the cost of the leaves $n^{\log_b a }= n^{\log_2 3} \approx n^{1.6}$, we are in the third case of the Master theorem.  This third case asks to also check if a certain regularity condition is satisfied, i.e. whether $af(n/b) \le cf(n)$ for some constant $c$ and all sufficiently larger $n$.  This can be verified to be true since $3 (n/2)^2 / (\log n/2) \le c n^2 / (\log n)$ for some constant $c$ and sufficiently large $n$. So, the third case of the Master theorem applies, and we get $T(n) = \Theta(f(n))$, which is $\Theta(n^2 / \log n)$.